# Visual Workflow Error in managed packages

Tags: managed-package, visual-workflow

I am playing around with Salesforce visual workflow but getting an error 'The (DB_Add_Object) element in your flow has validation errors.'

I'm just trying to create an object based on a few fields on a screen element.

When I manually create the Object it works fine and there are no validation rules on the object.

I also added a test screen before load to make sure the fields are populated alright.

My question is how can I debug visual workflow?  The debug log does not seem to have more detail on the error, am I missing something?

EDIT: From some more testing, it seems to be a managed package issue, something to do with the namespace I would assume.  Has anyone tried using the Create Record function in a managed package on a custom object?  It seems to work ok on standard objects.

Comment: Kris, I hope my answer helps you out! Just wondering if you might want to make the title of your question a bit more general? This will help others find out this information through future searches,e.g. How to handling / debug errors in Flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at **Fault Connector Overview** and **$Flow.FaultMessage** in the Flow [documentation](http://developer.financialforce.com/customizations/salesforce-flow-tool/). This will allow you to route any faults (which get swallowed by default). You can see it in action [here](http://developer.financialforce.com/customizations/salesforce-flow-tool/) as well, we recently published an article on using this fantastic tool!
[image]

Comment: Thanks for that, it is good to know but the error I am getting is either not getting caught in the Fault or $Flow.FaultMessage = 'The (DB_Add_Object) element in your flow has validation errors.'

Comment: I have actually found after hours of testing that flow can not update a custom objects in an org with a managed package, can anyone confirm that?

Comment: That is strange, I'm pretty sure our developer that worked on the article I linked in my answered did so on a managed install of our objects. I'll give this ago for you. Also wondering if enabling the regular Debug Logs will shed more light on your issue...

Comment: Ok just given it ago with a simple Create element against a managed object and it worked fine. Can you attach some screenshots of what your doing and the error perhaps?

Comment: I am actually talking about an org that has a managed packed built in it.  Not one that has had one installed.

Comment: Ok, let me give that a try for ya.... :)

Comment: Sorry still works fine for me in a packaging org. Not sure how else I can help here. Maybe worth raising a support case, as it could be something quirky with your Flow or environment. A screenshot or two might help, if your still looking for help here.

Comment: It was the flow I was using.  When I copied it, it still had that error but when I started a fresh and built exactly the same thing it worked fine.  Some extra error handling would be helpful :)